# Found difficult to make sql query

Tags: mysql, database

I checked the data is coming in the $posts_not_to_select as simple array and everything other is fine but it is showing me error shown below :

> Exception #0 (Zend_Db_Statement_Exception): SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax
>   error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near 'WHERE `entity_id` NOT IN (SELECT post_id
>   FROM mst_blog_store_post WHERE NOT stor' at line 1, query was: SELECT
>   * FROM `mst_blog_post_entity` ORDER BY `created_at` DESC LIMIT 1 WHERE `entity_id` NOT IN (SELECT post_id FROM mst_blog_store_post WHERE NOT
>   store_id = 1)

```
$posts_not_to_selectssql1 = "SELECT post_id FROM mst_blog_store_post WHERE NOT store_id = $storeID";
    $posts_not_to_select12 = $connection->fetchAll($posts_not_to_selectssql1);
    $posts_not_to_select = array();

    foreach ($posts_not_to_select12 as $key => $value){
        $posts_not_to_select[$key] = $value['post_id'];
    }

    "SELECT * FROM `mst_blog_post_entity` ORDER BY `created_at` ASC LIMIT 1 WHERE `entity_id` NOT IN ( '" . implode( "', '" , $posts_not_to_select ) . "' )"
```

Comment: Regardless of your choice of database, all SQL queries adhere to some form of syntax. If you ignore your choice of database's syntax, you're not going to get very far :-( -- also, you seems to have more queries here than is strictly necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ORDER BY` comes after `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT * FROM `mst_blog_post_entity` 
WHERE `entity_id` NOT IN ( '" . implode( "', '" , $posts_not_to_select ) . "' )"  
ORDER BY `created_at` ASC LIMIT 1
```

Complete sequence would be:

- SELECT
- FROM
- JOIN [ON]
- WHERE
- GROUP BY
- HAVING
- ORDER BY [LIMIT]

Comment: what about AND and OR? i want to use AND can I use that just after that NOT IN condition?

Comment: @CrackIt yes you can use `AND/OR` etc in `WHERE`

Comment: Thanks For your great help

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM `mst_blog_post_entity` WHERE `entity_id` NOT IN ( '" . implode( "', '" , $posts_not_to_select ) . "' )" ORDER BY `created_at` ASC LIMIT 1;
```

Just run this query in SQL section of phpmyadmin and everything will work just fine.